# Dreamweaver document settings

Tags: dreamweaver

Is there a way to change document settings in Dreamweaver like changing document background to black and plain text to white?  I prefer a dark background when reading code like the snippets [here](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/docs-and-demos.html).   Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change quite a few settings to do this, but there [appears](http://blogs.adobe.com/dreamweaver/2010/06/dark_background_color_in_dream.html) to be an extension.  Haven`t used it myself, but I know others have mentioned using it.

Comment: Perfecto, just what I was looking for.  Thanks for that.